# how to send value from one class into different classes(more than one class)

Tags: java, android, bundle

I have value `strUser` and `KEY` ,I want to send this value to multiple different classes because this value will be used in 5 classes for url, I know the way to send value to one class only using `Intent.putExtra` as bellow :

```
Intent policy= new Intent(LoginActivity.this,EpolicyListPolis.class);
        policy.putExtra("etUser",strUser);
        policy.putExtra("key",KEY);
        startActivity(policy);
```

How can I send this value to multiple different classes at a time? can i use SharedPrefences..? how the way i write sharedPrefences in class and my destination class?

Comment: Are all these 5 classes extending Activity class?

Comment: use intent again to send the value form this class to another class or use application class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: are all the values static means are they all changes class by class or it is fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

For storing values into `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("etUser", strUser);
editor.putString("key",KEY);
editor.commit();
```

Just paste these lines before calling `startActivity(policy);`

And get values from `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0);
String etUser1 = settings.getString("etUser", null);
String key1 = settings.getString("key", null);
```

And paste these lines at where you want `etUser1` and `key1`. You can access this `SharedPreferences` value in any `Activity`. If you cant please take a look on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values). It may help you.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: can you explain more about it..? how if i want to send value  strUser and KEY ?

Comment: i have tried it. But I can't seem to get the data to be shared between any of my activities...

Comment: @AoyamaNanami For full code example please see my blog post [here](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2012/12/shared-preferences.html) Aoyama

Comment: Same syntax. You can store and retrive any values in shared preference.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

send value from this class with **Intent**....

```
Intent policy= new Intent(LoginActivity.this,EpolicyListPolis.class);
    policy.putExtra("key",strUser);
    startActivity(policy);
```

this works like: **KEY**-"*key*" and **VALUE**-*strUser*.
and you get this *value from another class using KEY*.

Get value like this.

```
String user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key",null);
```

in **user** you get **strUser** value. and if strUser not pass any value than *default* **null**(right side of "key") asign for user....

same you use from all class you need... but remember all *works with KEY*...

because **KEY**(one type of ID) is only which is works to **Put** and **Get** particular value.....

Comment: all that i want is send value strUser and KEY into different class more than one class

Comment: your Intent redirect to only one class at a time and sequentially you use this for all class you need... both value pass by putExtra() and get by getExtra().

Comment: more detail about getExtra() check..http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29

Comment: and about putExtra() check...http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dependency injection create a Model which hold your states in value objects.
Then inject this model in your activities.

Or simply create a Singleton State object which can be referenced from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just get these things in the other activity--

```
   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
   String user = bundle.getString("etUser");
   String key = bundle.getString("key");
```

Or,

you can set these values in a class and get from them whereever you need.

Comment: how to call it in other class?

Comment: just call it in onCreate() method of other activity. If the class doesn't extend to activity then set the values in a class and get from them to your required class

Comment: i still don't understand... 
can you explain for detail?

Comment: make a class...set the vales etUser and key in it and make method to get these vales...and get to your required class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to do, but IMO, if i will use a variable from one class to another, i will make the variable static and "get" the value of that variable from the class..

for example in one class i have a variable:

```
public class Login extends Activity {

static String username;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
       this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

       username = "Your Name";
    }
```

and in another class, i would get that value like this;

```
   String var;
   var = Login.username;
```

but as i've read, this is not the best practice. Sometimes it just sufficient.

Comment: can you tell me the detail?

Answer (score 0):

First, get the intent which has started your activity using the `getIntent()` method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

If your extra data is represented as strings, then you can use `intent.getStringExtra()` method.

```
String etUser = intent.getStringExtra("etUser");
String key = intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to tell you to use Application class. The better idea to get the reference from the following link

[maintain the state of all the variables from the Application class](http://typicaljava.blogspot.in/2012/03/maintaining-stat-of-user-in-android.html)

Bettter to go for this Application b'coz you can access all the variables in every class with out sending from intent.

This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Application Object are some way, i would go for EventBus (like OTTO from Square or Greenrobot).
Do everting on Application Context tend to create the "GOD Object" problem after quite some time. You should avoid this. SharedPreferences are also some good option.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Bundle for pasing data form one Activity class to other Activity class Like this

```
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Id", videoChannelId);
    bundle.putString("C/V", "C");
    bundle.putString("mode", "ch");
    bundle.putString("code", "LiveTV");
    bundle.putString("urlcount", "2");
    Intent intent = new Intent(First.this,Second.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Get the data in the second class like this by giving the bundle id

```
     Bundle  getBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

     name = getBundle.getString("Url") 
      etc......
```